# Creating a NuGet Package That Makes Changes to the Solution

Tags: xamarin, nuget, mvvmcross

I've been using MvvmCross within a Xamarin mobile app, I've noticed that when I install the MvvmCross NuGet package that is makes changes to the solution by adding files and folders that it needs.

I'm curious as to how this is done so I can consider doing something similar in packages I publish?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to have NuGet add files to the project is to include a content directory inside your NuGet package (.nupkg). This is what the MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries NuGet package does. If you look inside that NuGet package you will see the following directory and file structure:

```
content
    MonoAndroid
        Resources
        ToDo-MvvmCross
        Views
        DebugTrace.cs.pp
        LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp
    MonoMac
    net45
    netcore45
    portable-win%2Bnet45%2Bwp8%2Bwin8%2Bwpa81
    win81
    wp8
    wpa81
    Xamarin.iOS10
```

I am only showing the contents of the MonoAndroid directory above. Files inside the content directory will be added to the project if it has a matching target framework (e.g. MonoAndroid).

The MvvmCross NuGet package also contains .cs.pp files which are C# files that have placeholders for certain values (e.g. $rootnamespace$) that will be replaced when the file is added to the project.